# Unable to use UFW after reinstalling python

Tags: 18.04, python, ufw

After reinstalling python and ufw I get the following error:

```
user@machine:~$ sudo ufw status
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/ufw", line 25, in <module>
    import ufw.frontend
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ufw'
```

I have tried to reinstall ufw multiple times but I don't get it to work.

What I have noticed about `pip` is that `sudo` uses `pip2` instead of `pip3` but also uses `python3` as `python`:

```
user@machine:~$ pip -V
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
user@machine:~$ sudo pip -V
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
user@machine:~$ sudo -i
root@machine:~# pip -V
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

user@machine:~$ python -V
Python 3.8.0
user@machine:~$ sudo python -V
Python 3.8.0
user@machine:~$ sudo -i
root@machine:~# python -V
Python 3.8.0
```

I am not sure if that causes the problems though.

Apt history:

```
apt remove --purge python3-pip # This broke ufw probably because --purge
apt remove python3
apt install python3 
apt remove python3 # Noticed outdated version, uninstall again and built from source afterwards
apt install python3-pip # Was done after building and installing python3 from source
```

`sudo pip3 list`:

```
Package    Version
---------- ---------
certifi    2019.9.11
chardet    3.0.4
idna       2.8
pip        19.3.1
requests   2.22.0
setuptools 41.2.0
urllib3    1.25.7
```

`python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.version); print(sys.path)'`:

```
3.8.0 (default, Dec  1 2019, 09:38:21)
[GCC 7.4.0]
['', '/usr/local/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8', '/usr/local/lib/                                                      python3.8/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
```

`ls /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw/`

```
applications.py  backend_iptables.py  backend.py  common.py  frontend.py  __init__.py  parser.py  __pycache__  util.py
```

Comment: Please edit your question to clearly describe exactly (step-by-step) how you "reinstall[ed] python and ufw." The details matter. If you were following online instructions, please provide a link. Also, please describe the issue you encountered that made such a reinstall seems desirable.

Comment: I added it to my original question.

Comment: Hmmm. Purging `python3` should have broken `apt`, rendering `apt` impotent and incapable of installing (or reinstalling) anything. If your `apt` still functioned, then something else is going on that we don't know about.

Comment: Tbh, I do not remember if I used purge or not. It was a few days ago. Quite possible I did not, since you say it would have rendered apt unusable. I will remove it from the question.

Comment: I suggest looking in /var/log/apt/history.log. It will tell you what you did, and what the result was. Copy and paste the entire session into your Question above, if possible.

Comment: I added the apt history.

Comment: Please also [edit] your question with the results of the following commands: `python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.version); print(sys.path)'` and `ls  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw/`.

Comment: @Kaz Wolfe Done

Comment: You said you tried to reinstall ufw but never posted the error it provided - this is the most important part imho.

Comment: Use pip3 not pip (also) as I recall

Answer (score 6):

You are not supposed to remove `python` from Ubuntu because a lot of packages are built on it. Since you have already installed python, please execute the commands listed below to reinstall `ufw`

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove ufw
sudo apt-get install ufw
```

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Comment: Well, the last resort for you is to backup your data and re-install Ubuntu. By removing python, you might have broken the dependencies of ufw

Comment: Seems unlikely: See https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/ufw . The `ufw` package in 18.04 is built against Python3, not Python2. Py2 is not a dependency of `ufw`.

Comment: Telling to reinstall stuff without telling **why** that helps is bad.

Comment: @Bobface what error is that?  You never posted the error you got from this in your original post!  You only posted python pip output - post the error from apt you get when trying to reinstall ufw!

Answer (score 4):

It seems `ufw` was removed from `pip3`, when you have uninstalled `python3-pip`

Try this to reinstall it:

```
sudo pip3 install https://launchpad.net/ufw/0.36/0.36/+download/ufw-0.36.tar.gz
```

Comment: There seems to be no package called `ufw`: `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ufw (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ufw`

Comment: @thesys, it works perfectly on my machine, so I assume that the problem is with `pip3`. So, edit the question to include the output of `pip3 list`

Comment: I added it to the question. Though it seems like `pip3` cannot find find a `ufw` package at all.

Comment: @thesys, I updated the answer. Try this command.

Comment: The command fails with the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.`

Googleing this error showed a Stackoverflow question with the answer to `sudo apt-get install libffi-dev` - I did that but still get the same error.

Comment: @thesys, You should recompile python after installing `libffi-dev` to make this package work, as you did earlier: Remove existing python, compile and install it.

Comment: Okay, it worked now. But I still get the same error as in my question unfortunately ("no module named ufw")

Comment: @thesys, does `ufw` appear in your `pip3 list` after installing?

Comment: Yes it does: `ufw        0.36`. I also reinstalled `ufw` but it does not help.

Comment: @thesys, I am sorry, I could not figure it out how to help you in this particular situation (I thought the problem is with `pip3`, but this was not the case). Check the answer given by @ketan-patel, it will surely help you.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like python version ufw was using is removed and installed version is different than it was,  So ufw is reporting error.

You can traceback which python version ufw is using by following command.

```
sudo find /usr/lib/ -name "ufw"
```

For example, You will have output similar below (exact depends on your python version ufw is using).

```
/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ufw
```

In above example, ufw is using python 3.6. 
You need to re-install particular python version according to your case.

Comment: The output is: `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ufw` and 
`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw`. It just says python3. Which version should I use?

Comment: You already have installed python 3.8 so proceed with installing python 2.7. Package is python.

Comment: Python 2.7 is also installed already.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 18.04, all dependency are automatically handled by package manager. You suppose not to manually install dependency.

It seems like you are using python package which is not compatible with UFW. If you don't have python project running, try to remove python and allow UFW to reinstall with dependency automatically.

Stop the process, if you get message like other package will get removed.

Still problem. Try :

sudo apt install aptitude

sudo aptitude install ufw

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the question is still relevant to the OP, but I was having the same problem today, so I'll share this with anyone who's going through the same problem.

I had Python 3.5 installed in a Debian machine and had to install a newer version of Python (since I had scripts with 'f-strings' and other features).

After installing the new version of Python (3.9 in my case), I would get the same result from `sudo ufw status`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/ufw", line 26, in <module>
    import ufw.frontend
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ufw'
```

After spending a few hours trying to figure out how to correct this, I managed to do it by getting the **ufw package** from the previous installed Python packages folder (in my case it was **/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw**) and copying this folder with all its content to the directory with the packages for the new version of Python (in my case, it was **/usr/local/lib/python3.9/**), so in the end I had something like this:

```
usr
│   ...
└───local
    │   ...
    └───lib
        │   ...
        └───python3.9
            │   ...
            └───ufw
                │   applications.py
                │   backend_iptables.py
                │   backend.py
                │   common.py
                │   frontend.py
                │   __init__.py
                │   parser.py
                │   util.py
```

The paths might change depending on the Python version you're working with, but this procedure solved my problem.

In a nutshell, all I did was copying the **ufw package** from the previous installed Python's dist-packages folder to the packages folder for the new version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/sbin/ufw", line 25, in <module>
    import ufw.frontend

~~~~ (fix) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: my friend you have incompatabile version of python for ufw , ufw is not the problem..
~~ here is a python switcher program ~~~
note: you could just set new symbolic link for python but below is better i think.
~~~~~`
use below program to switch from python3.8 to python3.7 and then ufw should work..
~~~~~ (fix) ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
    (out)
    There are 2 choices for the alternative python3 (providing /usr/bin/python3).

    Selection    Path                Priority   Status
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    * 0            /usr/bin/python3.7   1         auto mode
    1            /usr/bin/python3.7   1         manual mode
    2            /usr/bin/python3.8   2         manual mode

~(cont)~~ important note for python package ver support~~
to find what ver of python ufw supports go to:
https://pypi.org/
  (enter in ufw)
  (click on  ufw-config 0.0.X)
  (now look in lower left and see it must be <3.10)

Author: NeonDevelopment
Requires: Python >=3.6, <3.10
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, so I'll share a solution here.
Create a file e.g **pyprint** with this content:
*#! /usr/bin/python3

import sys

print(sys.path)*

Make it executable:
**chmod a+x pyprint**

You have to run ufw as sudo, so run this file as sudo:
**sudo ./pyprint**
*Output:*
*['/home/xxx', '/usr/local/lib/python311.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.11', '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages']*

Find your old python installation with ufw:
**sudo find /usr/lib/ -name "ufw"**
*Output:*
*/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw*

Copy directory **ufw** to a location found with **pyprint**.
In my case:
**sudo cp -r /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages**

Now test with:
**sudo ufw status**
*Output:*
*Status: inactive*

Answer (score 0):

@Renato - Thanks man, I fixed the issue using your fix.
In my case, I am on ubuntun 22.04 and using python 11.0. Bumping up my python version to match my django app broke things.

Here's how I do as per your suggestion:

1. Find ufw on my system using `sudo find /usr/lib/ -name "ufw"`
2. Once you find the path from (1), `cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/`
3. Then move the entire ufw folder to your Python3.11 version by doing `mv ufw /usr/local/lib/python3.11/`
4. Running ls command, the contents of ufw should look like this `dummyuser@svr01:/usr/local/lib/python3.11/ufw$ ls applications.py  backend_iptables.py  backend.py  common.py  frontend.py  __init__.py  parser.py  __pycache__  util.py`